# PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in line 762

Tags: php

last "}" is line 762. log says "PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '}' in /home/u230748479/public_html/application/controllers/api_new.php on line 762" if you need whole code ill send you. please help me. thanks.

```
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6DjyTFNtfv5SjZBM2JGNVh2V2c
```

link to my php file

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: You're most likely missing an opening bracket {. You'll have to make sure they are balanced.

Comment: Use a code indenter and you'll see yourself which bracket you are missing

Comment: it can either mean that it's already closed or something else that should've been closed isn't. Either way, I can't tell from this small snippet.

Comment: thanks to all, i added link to my file. please help me out. thanks

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I actually stopped scanning when I hit your poorly tabbed and formatted condition statements.  Helping you would actually be rewarding bad behavior.  You need to slave away at that file and properly tab and align your else statements so that you (and anyone else) can read it AND you can easily debug it.  After you have tidied up your code, if you can't find the error, then post your code and we will help you.  (I will remove my downvote if you fix your code.)

Comment: I looked at your code, but I didn't execute it. I cannot, by inspecting the code, see any bracket that is not balanced. The code doesn't help, just like mickmackusa says. For one it isn't DRY (do not repeat yourself). I had trouble locating stuff because all methods look alike.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your code, but you got 3 invalid (`\u007F`) characters before the `}` that gives the error.

This is your code

```
    echo "1";

    }
    // this line contains 3 invalid characters (\u007F = DELETE character)

} // this is line 762
```

Remove the line with the invalid characters and you should be good to go.

Comment: Please don't post answers on obviously off-topic questions! [See: **Should one advise on off topic questions?**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276572/1768232) Off-topic questions can be closed and deleted, which could nullify your contribution.